# Why do MVCs tend to convert objects into arrays when passing them off to a view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view

Why do MVCs tend to convert objects into arrays when passing them off to a view?

Just curious if there is a reason for this.

Comment: With all the differing "MVCs" out there I'm not sure you can say "they" "tend" to do anything, specifics please.

Comment: Actually, in the real MVC pattern the View communicates with the Model. It's just in Web-PMVC frameworks that there's partial data pushing.

Comment: @mario That distinction is quibble. MVC is a *web pattern* in POEAA. The most important aspect of it is separating the model from UI and that's the same for any environment, be it Smalltalk or PHP. Anything else is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Gordon. [Hardly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework/1549970#1549970) Failing to understand the transposition of the variations is a recipe for unsensible code. If people implement shallow models (= just database API) and a dumb view (= static page output instead of running widgets), then necessarily the so called "controller" needs to be fat. MVP and MVVM are better guides for that (and have supplanted MVC for a reason).

Comment: @mario That has nothing to do with whether it's MVC, MVP or XYZVC. It's just people not getting the fundamental difference between what belongs to the model and what belongs to the V and C. If people understand that V and C are the presentation layer and M is everything else and they should separate those, then it doesnt matter how they communicate as long as that distinction is maintained.

Comment: @Gordon. That's what I'm saying. People need to distinguish the intention from the buzzword. Saying MVC MVC MVC MVC MVC fifty times in a row or labeling classes after an inappropriate pattern does not aid this understanding. Which is the explanation for the *regular* inquiries here of how to organize that separation of concerns.

Comment: @mario I think the main reason why people misunderstand MVC is because RoR uses ActiveRecord and AR is mixing persistence and business logic (and ORM), so it effectively is Model = DB. This has nothing to do with MVC itself though. MVC does not say how you should implement your model. It just says split UI interaction into three roles. I agree people have to learn what MVC means, but I disagree that we should educate them with implementation details when the actual core aspect of MVC is just splitting M and VC.

Comment: @Gordon. True. Yet the majority of questions I see coming up on [php] quarrel exactly with the differentiation between MVC and PMVC. People do very well understand the outward properties of organizing the code into three parts. Yet the description and class names do not reflect what they read in tutorials or on e.g. Wikipedia about the original pattern (model = full business logic, controller = thin, view = user interface element). The better teminology would solve some of that confusion methinks.

Comment: @mario But then it has to be FCRCMCVT for FrontControllerRouterControllerModelControllerViewTemplate. That would also contain the control flow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by arrays, you mean sets, then the reason is because there is no guarantee that you only want to pass one object to the view.

Sure, you could have a context object that does pass all of your data to the view, but the frameworks would rather provide a mechanism for doing so that doesn't require you to aggregate your data, especially since it could take vastly different shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you should not be able to alter the object from within the view. I guess it just has to do with code purity and helping the user follow the MVC pattern.